# Error in MySQL group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using an SQL query in the form

```
   create table tb5
   SELECT count(*) as count, question, responsesummary, questionid from tb4 
   where responsesummary!= rightanswer group by  question,responsesummary
```

I am obtaining result as follows

```
        count                 question             responsesummary     id
         5                      q1                     abc            331
         6                      q1                     def            331
         5                      q1                     abc            331
```

Instead I want

```
       count                 question             responsesummary      id 
         10                      q1                     abc           331
         6                      q1                     def             331
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to add a new query to the existing result and get the desired output?

Comment: Add questionid tp the GROUP BY clause, or remove it from the select list.

Comment: Include questionid within the group clause, or aggregate it in some way, or remove it from the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*) as count, 
      question, 
      responsesummary,
      question_id
FROM tb5
WHERE responsesummary!= rightanswer GROUP BY responsesummary,question_id,question
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as count, question, responsesummary, questionid from tb4 
   where responsesu' at line 1

Comment: No luck. How does removing question id matter both the question and id are unique to a question? Can you suggest any query which would work if I add it to the existing result that is tb5?

Comment: You need to remove question_id because as shown in your output that you did not need it. Also, if you included it, be sure to cast an aggregate on it or put it in GROUP BY clause.Try again my query.

Comment: Based on your edit, I've changed my answer. Surely, it gives what you're looking for.^_^

Comment: This will only return me the responsesummary with maximum click. One option for one question. I need it for every option. Thanks anyways

Comment: You can remove the MAX in MAX(responsesummary), and put it in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Same output. I guess there might be something wrong in table. Thanks a lot. Respnsesummary may be looking equal but maybe they are not

Comment: Then atleast accept my answer to close your question. your always welcome.^^